# Is it ok to start a sentence with “also”?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, sentence-starts

Is it ok to start a sentence with *also*?

> Also, I had given him the file you sent me.

Comment: This reminds me of that scene from "Curb your enthusiasm". A conversation with Mel Brooks. "How do these things work, Andreas?" And he said, "Or you got it or you ain't." I said, "You're Greek, Andreas. We don't start sentences with 'or' in America."

Comment: @JSB: Why did you delete [tag:word-order]? Not that it matters to me, but I don't understand.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Certainly*, it is correct to begin a sentence with [*also*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/also). All adverbs (*also* inclusive) can be used at the beginning of a sentence with the proper punctuation. For instance, the first sentence in this answer begins with an adverb. Other examples are:

> - *Furthermore*, we have exhausted all the other options.
> - *Definitely*, you can use my car.
> - *Surely*, he could do better.
> - *Besides**, she had my number and could have called.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>*Note that *Besides* is used here as an adverb not a preposition.</sup>

Comment: It is capable of what?

Comment: @Ben: Oops! I meant *It can be used to begin a sentence* but I realize now that is not a direct answer. Should have been *Certainly, it is [correct, blah blah blah]* Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: -1 I don't think this is a balanced view. There is no rider about 'continuing a line of thought' [cf. Eduardo], 'marked feature of uneducated speech' [cf. Cerberus] or other exceptions. Unqualified OK to its use?

Comment: The point is, one can have a grammatical sentence beginning with an  adverb. Context is irrelevant. Some like it; some do not. I maintain, however, that is perfectly correct to do so. Inelegant, maybe, but not ungrammatical.

Comment: Why do you think the OP was asking about grammaticality in the linguistic sense? He seemed to be asking about both grammar and style to me. // And why should the same rule apply to all adverbs? To me, *also* is a special adverb.

Comment: @Kris continuing a line of thought is certainly implied and either obvious or dramatic (a character comes on stage and starts with "also" lettings us we've missed an earlier part of the conversation). Presumably that's why the querent wants to start with with a word with "also"'s meaning.
Of the four examples above, only the first sounds uneducated (because it sounds like an uneducated person using a larger word than the best choice, to sound educated) but that would depend on context, which the example doesn't give us - it could be perfectly fine in a wider real context.

Comment: @JonHanna In case the Q. relates to 'wider real context', then it rightly belongs in writersSE, doesn't it? On the other hand, if it were purely a question of grammar, as it appears on englishSE rather, then it remains debatable I suppose.

Comment: @Kris the opposite surely. A wider real context could justify the use of a word that is often better served by another, but that context would likely be debatable. As purely a matter of grammar, there's nothing wrong with "furthermore" here; that it's correct English grammar is a matter of fact.

Answer (score 14):

As noted by other commenters, some writers prefer to avoid "Also, .. " in formal writing. But there is one use of 'also' at the start of a sentence which is in fact more prevalent in formal than in informal writing: namely, Also + adjective. Example:

- Also important is the pursuit of wealth and economic growth and power.

This uncommon syntax is called "fronting'.

Comment: I like this answer too!

Answer (score 9):

Burchfield in *Fowler's Modern English Usage* advises against it. He says it is now quite frequent, but still a "marked feature of uneducated speech".

I have always disliked it myself; a sentence can easily be recast to avoid it. I see it a lot, even in academic writing; but it is still considered informal or uneducated by some (it is hard to estimate their number, but they are probably a small minority); so, if you want to please traditionalists, don't use it. If formality and style are not your primary concern, don't bother trying to avoid it, and rest assured that most people would use it.

Comment: +1 Folks, perfect grammatical sentences can also have some "marked feature of uneducated speech". So, check, always.

Comment: Burchfield would have found much of my college-educated acquaintance to be uneducated, apparently. In addition to the academic writing you cite; those writing the academic papers must be uneducated as well, to Burchfield's mind.

Comment: @sq33G I wouldn't worry about it, he'd apparently find Fowler's writing to be uneducated too.

Answer (score 5):

It is correct as long as you are continuing a line of thought, but you should limit its use to an informal register. Formal register, however, will require you to use a more sophisticated alternative such as Furthermore, to name one.

Comment: +1 This is more like it. I think even *Furthermore* or similar alternatives would be no better where *Also* doesn't sound right.

Comment: "Furthermore" is harder to use in a non-clumsy way. It's common in the sort of bad business-writing where writers strive to convince the reader they are smart, at the expense of not actually conveying anything else.
Not that it can't be used well, like anything else, but it shouldn't be used where "And" or "Also" will serve well. If needs must, perhaps copy Shakespeare's example of starting with "And furthermore", where the clear "And" starts the thought while the "furthermore" underlines that the point is additional.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Also, it's fine to start a sentence with *And*, *But* and many other words (mostly conjunctions) that some people are convinced they shouldn't start with.

Comment: But sentences starting with *And*, *But* and many other words (mostly conjunctions) will mostly apply to informal registers, like this one. However, *Furthermore* and *However* will turn your uneducated writing, by definition, into an educated one, like this one! Considering, of course, that educated people like to yell from time to time.

Comment: @Eduardo my educators valued poetry over count of syllables, and would consider *And* and *But* to serve more sentences better than *However* and much better than *Furthermore*.

Comment: I've butted heads with some who were convinced that you shouldn't start a sentence with a conjunction, but they've never fully convinced me that it's always wrong.  I've seen plenty of quality writing start a sentence with "but," particularly when discussing two sides of a complex issue.

Comment: @J.R. Some of the greatest writing does it a lot. I believe a lot of it starts from teachers trying to restrain young pupils writing "And then we went to the park. And then I played on the swings. And then my friend came. And then we had burgers for lunch...." with the result that correction of an over-use becomes a "rule" people believe in. Ironically, Eduardo above suggests "However" is okay despite there being further "rules" against that, though it's another zombie-rule really. That said, overuse of it will read even worse than overuse of other sentence-starting conjunctions.

Comment: I just realized, you started your sentence with a conjunction, and ended it with a preposition!  Was that intentional, or accidental?  Either way, it's classic!  +1

Comment: @J.R. Quite intentional, as was the use of passive voice. I was tempted to split the infinitive "to start" as "to just start" or "to sometimes start", but it would have been weaker than as-is, and so worked counter to my argument. Breaking a rule for stronger writing is fine, especially when it's a "zombie rule" (not really a rule at all), but not for weaker writing.
If written today I'd perhaps have added a sentence starting with "However", to catch the controversy about the Associated Press style guide changing to allow it.

Comment: @J.R. (Though I started with an adverb rather than a conjunction, specifically the adverb that the question asked about starting sentences with).

Answer (score 2):

This usage is very much correct. Especially when you are continuing the sentence from the other person.

Let's look at an example conversation:

> Person A: John has taken more than one hour now, to get the medicine from the store. I even made sure he got the right direction.
>
> Person B: Also, I had given him my car to drive, so that he can reach quickly.

Comment: Also, Person B: "Plus, I had given him my car to drive, so that he can reach quickly." -- in contemporary speech.

Answer (score 2):

As always, it's not a matter of what's correct, but rather of what works in a given context. Starting a sentence with *also* may be effective for some communicative purposes, but not for others. It just isn't possible to give a single answer to such a general question.