# Synonyms of " in the case of"

Tags: word-choice

Is there any word with the same meaning as *in the case of*? How we can say it in different ways if in one paragraph we have several copies of *in the case of*?

Comment: Thanks, One more question. In formal texts can we write "also" at start, and do we need comma both before and after "in the case of", that is, is this correct? Also, in the case of,

Comment: For the use of 'also', please have a look here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171307/use-of-also-vs-and-also

Comment: 'Also, in the case of', is correct expression!

Answer (score 4):

*in the case of*:

- Regarding
- In the matter of
- In that instance.

Answer (score 2):

- In connection with
- As regards
- In relation to
- With reference to
- In that connection
- Bearing on
- Connected with

Answer (score 1):

In regard to...

With regard to...

With respect to...

As far as...is/are concerned...

as far as...goes/go...