# To get rid of "also" in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: phrase-requests

> Also, use them where you need to process multiple statements at once.

As I know, the use of "also" in the beginning of a sentence is somewhat debatable: [Is it ok to start a sentence with “also”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/54327)

How to change this phrase to get rid of it?

A complete text:

> - If a function or a command returns or sets the `ErrorLevel`, use `If (ErrorLevel != 0)`.
> - Otherwise, use `Try` and `Catch`.
> - Also, use `Try` and `Catch` where you need to process multiple statements at once.

Comment: What's the preceding sentence? It might make a difference on the choice of expression.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've edited the question.

Comment: One can also use them ...   Or:  They can also be used ...

Comment: I think "also" is absolutely fine where it is. You have a short list of tips for troubleshooting something (device, app?), so there's no need to add more words.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *also*. But it can be replaced with any number of [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/also) if desired.

Comment: @JasonBassford I expect that any admonishment against "also" would apply equally to a synonym -- the problem is the form, not the specific word.

Comment: @Barmar The question says that the use of the word is debatable, but it links to a question where the accepted answer says that it's acceptable. The only debate is if it's a style that should be used—not if it's grammatical. If the question is really to be answered outside of this, it needs to provide more detail as to *why* it might be "wrong," and, therefore, what *kind* of alteration is expected from us. Asking about synonyms is a way of clarifying if the problem here is the word itself or the structure of the sentence.

Comment: Maybe replace "Also, ..." with "You should also...." or "They should also be used...". But "Also, ..." is grammatically fine, and more succinct than the alternatives.